# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter

Tags: java, spring, logging, dependencies, slf4j

I am new in Spring with hibernate.I have tried to complete one simple application which contains bellow file.
1.Employee.java

```
    private int id;  
    private String name;  
    private float salary; 
//and setter and getter
```

2.Employee.hbm.xml (which contains all mapping details)

3.EmployeeDao.java

```
public class EmployeeDao {  
            HibernateTemplate template;  

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {  
        this.template = template;  
    }  
    //method to save employee  
    public void saveEmployee(Employee e){  
        template.save(e);  
    }  
    //method to update employee  
    public void updateEmployee(Employee e){  
        template.update(e);  
    }  
    //method to delete employee  
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee e){  
        template.delete(e);  
    }  
    //method to return one employee of given id  
    public Employee getById(int id){  
        Employee e=(Employee)template.get(Employee.class,id);  
        return e;  
    }  
    //method to return all employees  
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){  
        List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();  
        list=template.loadAll(Employee.class);  
        return list;  
    }  
  }
```

4.applicationContext.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

 <bean id="dataSource1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prasanta"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value=""></property> 
 </bean> 
 <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
            <list>  
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>  
            </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  --> 

            </props>  
        </property>  
  </bean>  
  <bean id="template1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
  </bean>
 <bean id="d" class="EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template1"></property>  
  </bean>
</beans>
```

5.Test.java as below:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
 import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
 import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  

 public class Test {  
        public static void main(String[] args) {  

        Resource r=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  

        EmployeeDao dao=(EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");  

        Employee e=new Employee();  
        e.setId(114);  
        e.setName("arun");  
        e.setSalary(50000);  

        dao.saveEmployee(e);  

    }  
 }
```

And I have added bellow jar files in build path.

```
spring-orm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.jar
com.springsource.org.hibernate.annotations.common-3.3.0.ga.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.3.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.3.Final.jar
org.apache.commons.pool.jar
javax.transaction.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.3.final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
dom4j.jar
slf4j.jar
logback-core-0.9.6.jar
logback-classic-0.9.jar
slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar
```

when try to run the appl. it throws  bellow Exception:

```
Mar 31, 2015 7:23:48 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.<init>(Lch/qos/logback/classic/LoggerContext;)V
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:56)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:189)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:112)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:105)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:235)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:813)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at Test.main(InsertTest.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template1' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template1' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at Test.main(InsertTest.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template1' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:813)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/MessageFormatter
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:114)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog(Logger.java:421)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog(Logger.java:430)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.debug(Logger.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register(BasicTypeRegistry.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.MessageFormatter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 47 more
```

I also tried by adding three more jar

```
cglib-2.2.2.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
```

and got same result.

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

`logback-classic-0.9.6.jar` `ContextInitializer.java` does not support the below constructor, which is why you are running  into the issue.

**Missing constructor**

```
public ContextInitializer(LoggerContext loggerContext) {
    this.loggerContext = loggerContext;
  }
```

Try upgrading to `logback-classic-1.0.0.jar` version.

Also switch to `slf4j-log4j12-1.0.1.jar`.